# memory_get_usage(true) vs Yii Debugger

Tags: php, memory, yii2

I am use Yii2. Who can help? memory_get_usage(true)  returns 8-9MB but in Yii Debbuger Memory:58.3MB. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As shown [in this file](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/blob/master/panels/ProfilingPanel.php#L74) Yii2-debug tool is using [memory_get_peak_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) function and that is not the same as [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) function. according to their respective documentations :

> memory_get_peak_usage — Returns the peak of memory allocated by PHP
>   memory_get_usage — Returns the amount of memory allocated to PHP

So the Yii-debugger tool is doing it right by returning the amount of memory being used instead of the amount allocated to php.

You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010781/php-memory-get-usage), [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206726/is-this-a-good-measure-of-php-script-usage-of-the-system) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745385/memory-get-peak-usage-with-real-usage) for more details.